# ui-router | resolve dependency | force reload | force refresh

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have this in my app.js:

```
.state('tab.interview', {
    url: '/interview/:survey_id',
    views: {
      'tab.interview': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab.interview.html',
        controller: 'interviewController'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      duh: function() {
        console.log('HOHOHO');
        return new Date();
      }
    }
  })
```

I have this in my tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Organizer" icon-off="ion-ios-list-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-list" ui-sref="tab.survey">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab.survey"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Interview" icon-off="ion-chatbox" icon-on="ion-chatbox-working" ui-sref="tab.interview" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, inherit: false}">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab.interview"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

You can see that I already have this options for the tab: ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, inherit: false}" . I thought it would force the reload of the controller, along with its resolve dependencies.

I have a controller like this:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
  console.log('.....');
  console.log(duh);
  console.log('.....');
});
```

What I'm seeing in the console is:

1. HOHOHO gets printed everytime I switch to that tab. This tells me new instance of "duh" dependency is created.
2. *But*... the console.log in the ionic.enter gives me the same value (the time the _first_time_ I load that tab). E.g.: Mon Dec 28 2015 08:26:02 GMT-0600. Always that same value. As if the newly created instance of duh (Date) was not (re)bound to that variable in the controller.

Where did I do wrong? It is essential for my app that the duh is refreshed everytime I switch to that tab (particular when the "reload" options in the $state.go is set to true).

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the cache for the given state:

```
.state('tab.interview', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/interview/:survey_id',
    views: {
      'tab.interview': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab.interview.html',
        controller: 'interviewController'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      duh: function() {
        console.log('HOHOHO');
        return new Date();
      }
    }
  })
```